# Getting the store ID when placing an admin order

Tags: admin, shipping-methods, store-id

I have a multisite setup with multiple custom shipping modules. Each store has different settings for free shipping etc.. (based on weight/value)

Everything works great from the front end, however on the backend the modules take the default values and do not recognize that a store has been selected.

I can detect if it is an admin order, but no idea how to detect what store has been selected and how to get the variables for that store

I am using the following

```
$current_cart_total_inc >=Mage::getStoreConfig('general/custom_values/free_ship_threshold');
```

How can I detect the store and then get the correct value based on the store ID rather than use the admin one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get store value with below code:
  to get store id in adminend

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');
```

for frontend

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$current_cart_total_inc = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/custom_values/free_ship_threshold', $store_id);
```

Comment: There is no orderID as this is a shipping module, the order does not exist yet

Comment: add the code for current store id you can check this

Comment: That does not work as the storeID is returned as 0 as it is an admin order

Comment: there is no store set for admin if you are creating the order then set the store by yourself. it work for frontend.

Comment: Yes but how can I tell what store the order is for, the store name is shown so there must be a way to detect what store has been selected before creating the order

Comment: you can do it after the order creation i added that code previously.

Comment: I can't do it after the order is placed, it is a shipping module, it needs to know the store so it can calculate the correct shipping costs

Comment: you can get selected store id in admin by `$this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with

$store_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');

$current_cart_total_inc = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/custom_values/free_ship_threshold', $store_id);

Now the shipping modules work frontend and back